# Find the Solution Set of $3^x = 2^x + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

So this is a problem, I've tried too hard to solve it, searched the internet for it, did all I could, but I had never found the solution.

I need to find the solution set of the equation with algebra only
$$3^x = 2^x + 1$$

Comment: You can solve it grafically

Comment: I know I could, and I've solved it graphically, but I need to solve it algebraically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$3^x = 2^x + 1 \Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$$

The LHS is increasing while the RHS is decreasing.

Compare what happens with the LHS vs RHS when $x >1$ and $x<1$. [Hint compare them with $\frac{3}{2}$]

Comment: When x = 1, L.H.S = R.H.S ---- When x > 1, L.H.S increases while R.H.S decreases, when x < 1, R.H.S decreases while R.H.S increases